# Append values automatically after facebook login is correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, cordova

I'm working on a cordova project and i'm using facebook login as one of the user authentication. The login works correctly but the issue is i have to press a button of an id `getinfo` before the values from facebook appear. But what i want to do is when the login is right the values should be appended automatically to the divs.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#login").on('click', function (event) {
        // Defaults to sessionStorage for storing the Facebook token
        openFB.init({ appId: '000000000000000' });

        //  Uncomment the line below to store the Facebook token in localStorage instead of sessionStorage
        //  openFB.init({appId: 'YOUR_FB_APP_ID', tokenStore: window.localStorage});

        openFB.login(
                function (data) {
                    if (data.status === 'connected') {
                        $id = $("#id").append(data.id)
                        $name = $("#name").append(data.name)
                        $gender = $("#gender").append(data.gender)
                        $email = $("#email").append(data.email)
                    } else {
                        alert('Facebook login failed: ' + data.error);
                    }
                });

    });
});
```

how do i make my script work without using this below function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#getinfo").on('click', function (event) {
        openFB.api({
            path: '/me',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                $id = $("#id").append(data.id)
                $name = $("#name").append(data.name)
                $gender = $("#gender").append(data.gender)
                $email = $("#email").append(data.email)
                document.getElementById("userPic").src = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + data.id + '/picture?type=small';
            },
            error: errorHandler
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: any error messages? did you debug it? that´s a lot of pointless jquery code, maybe you should learn vanilla javascript and forget about jquery for a while...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this login function:

```
openFB.login(
  function (data) {
    if (data.status === 'connected') {
      openFB.api({
            path: '/me',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                $id = $("#id").append(data.id)
                $name = $("#name").append(data.name)
                $gender = $("#gender").append(data.gender)
                $email = $("#email").append(data.email)
                document.getElementById("userPic").src = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + data.id + '/picture?type=small';
            },
            error: errorHandler
      });
    } else {
      alert('Facebook login failed: ' + data.error);
      }
  });
});
```